# ObservableCollection binary serialization and transfer over the network

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a small problem ka. there is a class

```
    public class PLayer
{
public String Name{get;set;}
public TimeSpan Tax { get; set; }

}
```

The main form

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public ObservableCollection<PLayer> PlayersInGame { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<PLayer> PlayersInGame2 { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<PLayer> PlayersOnBench { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
PlayersInGame = new ObservableCollection<PLayer>();
PlayersInGame2 = new ObservableCollection<PLayer>();

PlayersOnBench = new ObservableCollection<PLayer>();

InitializeComponent();

}


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
String vName = "Игрок" + i.ToString();
PlayersInGame.Add(new PLayer { Name = vName, Tax = new TimeSpan(0) });
}
for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
{
String vName = "Игрок" + i.ToString();
PlayersInGame2.Add(new PLayer { Name = vName, Tax = new TimeSpan(0) });
}
Game.Items.Refresh();
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
if (Game.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
var temp = PlayersInGame[Game.SelectedIndex];
//PlayersInGame.RemoveAt(Game.SelectedIndex);
temp.Tax = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
PlayersOnBench.Add(temp);
Game.Items.Refresh();
Bench.Items.Refresh();
}
if (Game2.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
var temp = PlayersInGame2[Game2.SelectedIndex];
//PlayersInGame2.RemoveAt(Game2.SelectedIndex);
temp.Tax = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
PlayersOnBench.Add(temp);
Game2.Items.Refresh();
Bench.Items.Refresh();
}
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (var x in PlayersOnBench)
{
x.Tax -= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
}

List<int> Temp = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < PlayersOnBench.Count; i++)
{
if (PlayersOnBench[i].Tax == TimeSpan.Zero)
{
Temp.Add(i);

}
}
for (int i = Temp.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
var s = PlayersOnBench[i];



PlayersOnBench.RemoveAt(Temp[i]);
//PlayersInGame.Add(s);
//Game.Items.Refresh();


}
Bench.Items.Refresh();
}
}
```

On the main form when you click on the button "Button2_Click" line is added to the ListView "Bench" with the addition of a timer. in the treatment of "timer_Tick" The timer is counting all the lines added to the "Bench". Contact ossushestvlyaetsya a Binding. My question is knowing binary serialization, how to transfer the contents of ListView "Bench" to the server to display in a ListView or ListBox. The binary serialization of the project has been in use for sending text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear on what you trying to achieve. In general, if you using binary serialization, it will convert your objects into byte array, you need to de-serialize inorder to get your object back. Below is a sample

```
    BinaryFormatter m_formatter;
    Byte[] m_stateData;
    List<T> cloned_objList;

    public binaryserializer(List<T> PlayersOnBench)
    {
        if ((!Object.ReferenceEquals(listToClone, null)) && (typeof(T).IsSerializable))
        {
            m_formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    m_formatter.Serialize(stream, PlayersOnBench);
                }
                catch { }

                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                m_stateData = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<T> BenchStates
    {
        get
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(m_stateData))
            {
                try
                {
                    cloned_objList = (List<T>)m_formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
            return cloned_objList;
        }
    }
```